# what is absolute path in C++/WinRT

Tags: console, visual-studio-2017, c++-winrt

the error: WinRT originate error-0x80070057:'The specified path (msappx:\Local\C:\Windows\Web\Screen\img103.png) is not an absolute path, and relative paths are not allowed. '

when I used C++/WinRT,the function call is
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperationwinrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile temp = StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(hFilname);

what can I do?

Comment: [URI schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes).

Comment: Has your question been solved? If not, please feel free to contact us.

Answer (score 0):

For `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync()` method, you don't have permission to access the specified file, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

My suggestion is that you could store the image file in **Application install directory** that app can access, then use the following code to access it.

```
StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;          
string path= Path.Combine(folder.Path, @"Data\img1.png");  
StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
```

Note that the Application install directory is **..ProjectPath\bin\x86\Debug\Appx**